# How can I write a Recursive NonNullable type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to create a function that works like [lodash's get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) but is typed.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function safeGet<T, R>(subject: T, select: (t: NonNullable<T>) => R): R | undefined {
  try { return select(subject); }
  catch { return undefined; }
}

// example use
interface MyType {
  someKey: {
    someValue: string | undefined;
  } | undefined
}

let exampleSubject: MyType = /* ... */;

const gotSomeValue = safeGet(exampleSubject, s => s.someKey.someValue)
```

This sort of works but it doesn't recursively remove undefined. Is there a way to create some sort of recursive `NonNullable` type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const RNN_ORIG = Symbol();
type RecursiveNonNullable1<T> = { [K in keyof T]: RecursiveNonNullable<T[K]> };
type RecursiveNonNullable<T> = RecursiveNonNullable1<NonNullable<T>> & {[RNN_ORIG]: T};

function safeGet<T, R extends { [RNN_ORIG]: unknown }>
  (subject: T, select: (t: RecursiveNonNullable<T>) => R): R[typeof RNN_ORIG] | undefined {
  try { return select(<any>subject); }
  catch { return undefined; }
}

// example use
interface MyType {
  someKey: {
    someValue: string | undefined;
  } | undefined
}

declare let exampleSubject: MyType;
const gotSomeValue = safeGet(exampleSubject, s => s.someKey.someValue)
```

Comment: thanks for the pure wizardry. this definitely answers my original question (so I marked it as accepted) but there's now an issue with that `safeGet` function I wrote above—since the return type is `R | undefined` the result of the function is a version of `RecursiveNonNullable1 | undefined` where it should be the nested original type of the nested original object. do you any ideas to make it the original type?

Comment: Updated the answer.  Let me know if you run into problems and I will see if I can solve them.

Comment: thanks, I finally used `type RecursiveNonNullable<T> = {[K in keyof T]-?: RecursiveNonNullable<NonNullable<T[K]>>};` to remove the Partial